# Get column values not exist in another column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframe df1 and df2, df1 & df2 have column "A". I want output df3 has column "A" which has values of df1 not exist on df2.

```
df1
```

| A |
| --- |
| I-13856942 |
| I-13856914 |
| I-13861633 |
| I-13875002 |
| I-13875673 |

df2

| A |
| --- |
| I-13856942 |
| I-13856914 |
| I-13861633 |

output
df3

| A |
| --- |
| I-13875002 |
| I-13875673 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
df1.loc[df1.merge(df2, how='left', indicator=True)['_merge'].eq('left_only'),:]
```

Output:

```
            A
3  I-13875002
4  I-13875673
```

Comment: when I run, I have this error "'Series' object has no attribute 'merge'"

Comment: 'Series' object has no attribute 'merge'

Comment: Right: Just do `df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)` and `df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)` before using my code. That is needed because your `df1` and `df2` are series and not dataframes.

Comment: MergeError: No common columns to perform merge on. Merge options: left_on=None, right_on=None, left_index=False, right_index=False

Comment: Does the column of each dataframe have the name `A`?

Comment: Do: `df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1, columns=['A'])` and `df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2, columns=['A'])`.

Comment: work now after restarting the kernel, thanks alot.